# Object required error in IF statement when using VBA

Tags: excel, if-statement, vba

I am fairly new to VBA, and I need to make a macro that checks every column from a database against a template table. I've gotten the code to work, but when I was moving things around to position the text to be displayed how I wanted, I kept getting an error "Object Required" at the If-statement. Any help would be appreciated.

```
Sub checkValues()
'Initalizes integers that will be used
Dim rwIndex As Long             '"Item Attributes" row index
Dim colIndex As Long            '"Item Attributes" column index
Dim rowEnd As Long              'Last row in "Item Attributes"
Dim colEnd As Long              'Last column in "Item Attributes"
Dim tempIndex As Integer        'Index used to move down 'Lookup Code' column in the template table
Dim resRow As Long              'Current row in "Report" to paste
Dim resCol As Long              'Current column in "Report" to paste

'Initializes the worksheets that will be usedd
Dim shnam1 As Worksheet
Dim shnam2 As Worksheet
Dim shnam3 As Worksheet

'Sets the worksheets for the workbook
Set shnam1 = Sheets("Item Attributes")
Set shnam2 = Sheets("Table")
Set shnam3 = Sheets("Report")

'Gets bounds for "Item Attributes" table
rowEnd = shnam1.Cells(Application.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
colEnd = shnam1.Cells(1, Application.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

Call clearReport(shnam3)       'Clear results before every use

'Let the user know that the report is being made
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.StatusBar = "Creating the report..."
Application.DisplayAlerts = True

'Report Heading
shnam3.Cells(1, 1).Value = "Oracle Part Number"
shnam3.Cells(1, 2).Value = "Description"
shnam3.Cells(1, 3).Value = "Attribute Name"
shnam3.Cells(1, 4).Value = "Attribute Value"
shnam3.Cells(1, 5).Value = "Correct Value"

resRow = 2                  'Set row for Results

'From 2nd row to last row
For rwIndex = 2 To rowEnd

    tempIndex = 3       'Template table index
    resCol = 1          'Set column for results

    'From 3rd column to last column
    For colIndex = 3 To colEnd

        'Compare selection in data to template table
        If (shnam1.Cells(rwIndex, colIndex).Value) <> (shnam2.Cells(tempIndex, 1).Value) Then

            'Copy oracle part number and description
            shnam1.Range(shnam1.Cells(rwIndex, 1), shnam1.Cells(rwIndex, 2)).Copy shnam3.Cells(resRow, resCol)

            'Copy attribute name
            shnam2.Cells(tempIndex, 2).Copy shnam3.Cells(resRow, resCol + 2)

            'Copy correct attribute value
            shnam2.Cells(tempIndex, 1).Copy shnam3.Cells(resRow, resCol + 3)

            'Copy incorrect attribute value
            shnam1.Cells(rwIndex, colIndex).Copy shnam3.Cells(resRow, resCol + 4)

            resRow = resRow + 1                 'Move down a row in the "Report" table

        End If

        tempIndex = tempIndex + 1           'Increment through template table

    Next colIndex

Next rwIndex

'Turn on screen updating
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

'Format "Report" table
Call formatReport(shnam3)

'Turn off status bar and display that the report has finished
Application.StatusBar = False
Msgbox "The report has been created."

End Sub

'Clear the "Report" table
Sub clearReport(shnam As Worksheet)
    shnam.Select
    Cells.Select
    Selection.ClearContents
End Sub

'Adjust all text to be orientated on the left in "Report" table
Sub formatReport(shnam As Worksheet)
    shnam.Select
    Cells.Select
    Selection.NumberFormat = "@"
End Sub
```

Comment: Try shnam1.Range(shnam1.Cells(rwIndex, 1), shnam1Cells(rwIndex, 2)).Copy instead of shnam1.Range(Cells(rwIndex, 1), Cells(rwIndex, 2)).Copy. If the sheet is not active, 'cells' doesn't reference the correct cells

Comment: Still getting the error 'Object Required' on the IF-statement. Would creating ranges for both, and just using offset to loop through be a better idea for me? Running this takes a little time because the database has 32000 rows and 48 columns.

Comment: Why are you declaring your worksheet objects as variants?

Comment: I've been trying to change things around to see it would help, orginally had it set as a String, and just used Worksheets("shnam1"). But that didn't change anything. I also tried declaring them as worksheets and nothing changed. But I will try that again right now to see if it makes it works.

Comment: I updated the post where I declared the worksheets as worksheets, but still nothing is changing.

Comment: I figured it out, I had misspelled the 2nd worksheet.

Comment: If you modify your copy/paste syntax, you should see a performance gain. (this method doesn't use the clipboard) `shnam1.Range(shnam1.Cells(rwIndex, 1), shnam1.Cells(rwIndex, 2)).Copy shnam3.Cells(resRow, resCol)`  (all on one row)

Comment: I'm getting an Application defined or Object defined error.

Comment: Nevermind, figured it out. I appreciate all the help. First VBA macro in the books.

Comment: Can someone explain to me why this caused the sheet that the items are copied to to have the scroll bar go down to very possible last row for the excel sheet, so 1,000,000 or so. I tried to delete the rows but nothing happened.

Comment: Might I suggest that you post an "answer to your own question" - that way people don't come looking "oh here is a question that hasn't been answered yet" - and they have to work their way through the comments to discover that actually, it has...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Made a simple mistake, correct and working code shown above.